# Как реализовать usb флешку с приглашением к установки приложения Android

Tags: android, android-sdk, usb, установка

Требуется создать программу для флешки которая при подключении к устройству под Android запустила бы приглашение на установку приложение с расширение .apk. Таким образом будто пользователь нажал на файл с расширение .apk и запустилась установка.

Как подобное можно было бы реализовать?